# How does Funambol work?

Tags: android, funambol

I'm developing a android application for a customer which involves capturing data on the handset and then synchronizing it later to a server. They want me to use Funambol server and client to sync data. I have tried looking up on the www.funambol.com website for any api and documentation, but am not able to find any library for android.

Has anyone done any similar work using funambol? I need to sync a list of customers and their related data which will be entered by a salesman.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Funambol has a syncml api for android that is used in the Android client, and can be used for performing the sync without the need of implementing syncml. You will only need to work on client and server side to implement the proper syncsource for your specific data, and store the data on both sides.
Take a look at https://www.forge.funambol.org/download/ (bottom of the page)

The developer community can be reached at bit.ly/fun-open-discuss, where you can discuss development topics and share your project and code (as required by AGPL).

Answer (score 0):

Funambol provides [open source-based solutions](https://android-client.forge.funambol.org/)  for push email & PIM sync as well as device management and a platform for mobilizing apps and data. Funambol is based on the SyncML (OMA DS) standard for data synchronization.

Read the [FAQ](https://help.forge.funambol.org/questions/faq.html)

Comment: Thanks Reno, what I'm looking for is a android library/api for me to sync custom data from my android application. The funambol Android client is a app available from the app market that syncs contacts, pictures and email. What I want is an API so that I can send customers from my SQLite database.

Comment: Read the answer : **Funambol is based on the SyncML (OMA DS) standard for data synchronization**. SyncML is a standard DS protocol by which you will send your customer data to their servers.

Comment: Reno, I know that> I have read the entire funambol website, downloaded the client, synched my contacts, photos and files. What I'm looking for is an android library/api for me to send my CUSTOM data from MY android app to a funambol server. If someone has developed an app, I would like a sample